# Problem with Project Euler Problem 12

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble with Project Euler's problem 12.  My code is correctly generating the series, as far as I can tell, and it gets the correct solution to the test problem. I don't believe that `long` is getting overflowed because it does return a solution, just not the correct one.  Any thoughts?

> The sequence of triangle numbers is
>   generated by adding the natural
>   numbers. So the 7th triangle number
>   would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 =
>   28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55,
>   ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first
>   seven triangle numbers:
>
> 1: 1  3: 1,3  6: 1,2,3,6 10: 1,2,5,10
>   15: 1,3,5,15 21: 1,3,7,21 28:
>   1,2,4,7,14,28 We can see that 28 is
>   the first triangle number to have over
>   five divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first
>   triangle number to have over five
>   hundred divisors?

```
class Program
{
    static long lastTriangle = 1;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long x = 1;
        do
        {
            x = nextTriangle(x);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        } while (numDivisors(x) < 500);

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static long nextTriangle(long arg)
    {
        lastTriangle += 1;
        long toReturn = lastTriangle + arg;
        return toReturn;
    }

    static long numDivisors(long arg)
    {
        long count = 0;
        long lastDivisor = 0;
        Boolean atHalfWay = false;
        for (long x = 1; x <= arg && !atHalfWay; x++)
        {
            if (arg % x == 0 && x != lastDivisor)
            {
                count++;
                lastDivisor = arg / x;
            }
            else if (x == lastDivisor)
            {
                atHalfWay = true;

            }
        }
        return count*2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `x` is a square `numDivisors` counts the square root of `x` twice.

Comment: I added the code
'            if (Math.Sqrt(arg) % 1 == 0)
                return count * 2 - 1;'
to account for squares.  I'm getting a different but stil incorrect solution.

Comment: Actually, I just realized what you were doing with that condition, and it should work in principle, but because Sqrt returns a double it might not be exact. I think `if(lastDivisor*lastDivisor == arg)` is a safer test.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that the square roots of perfect squares are counted twice. When arg is a square, `numDivisors(arg)` gives a completely wrong answer, not just one off. Consider `arg = 36`. When `x = 4`, lastDivisor gets set to 9. Next iteration, `x = 5;`

```
if (36 % 5 == 0 && 5 != 9) // 36 % 5 == 1
else if (5 == 9)
// Nothing done, next x
if (36 % 6 == 0 && 6 != 9) // true
{
    count++;
    lastDivisor = 36 / 6; // 6
}
// next x
if (36 % 7 == 0 && 7 != 6) // 36 % 7 == 1
else if (7 == 6)
// next x
```

Now x will never equal lastDivisor and the loop runs until `x == 36`, so *all* divisors are counted twice.

Another mistake your condition `while (numDivisors(x) < 500)`, the problem asks for the first triangle number with *more than* 500 divisors, if there was one with exactly 500 divisors before, you'd find that.

Exercise for the reader: why is it - in the problem as stated - not necessary to check for squares and count the square root only once?